# PHP Check User Script not working

Tags: php, authentication, members

I've stumbled upon a bit of a problem. My checkuser.php isn't redirecting as it should to the members area page.

Basically login.html sends to checkuser.php which should then redirect to login_success.php

Here's the code `

```
<?
/* Check User Script */
session_start();  // Start Session

include 'db.php';
// Conver to simple variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if((!$username) || (!$password)){
    echo "Please enter ALL of the information! <br />";
    include 'login_form.html';
    exit();
}

// Convert password to md5 hash
$password = md5($password);

// check if the user info validates the db
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' AND activated='1'");
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($login_check > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
        $$key = stripslashes( $val );
    }
        // Register some session variables!
        session_register('first_name');
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
        session_register('last_name');
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
        session_register('email_address');
        $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
        session_register('special_user');
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_login=now() WHERE userid='$userid'");

        header("Location: login_success.php");
    }
} else {
    echo "You could not be logged in! Either the username and password do not match or you have not validated your membership!<br />
    Please try again!<br />";
    include 'login_form.html';
}
?>
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and `session_register()` is pointless unless you're on a primordial-slime-era version of PHP. Just do `$_SESSION[...] = ...` instead.

Comment: Also `mysql_` functions are deprecated and please don't use `md5` for password hashing.

Comment: What did you try ? Do you go into `if($login_check > 0){` for example?

Comment: Okay, UPDATE! This was surrounded by HTML and after removing the HTML the code now works. Can anyone explain why that could be?

Comment: Regarding the SQL Injection attacks, can anyone suggest fixes or would I be better to modernise and start a fresh?

Answer (score 1):

you are not supposed to echo/print something before you

```
header("Location: login_success.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove a $

```
 foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
        $$key = stripslashes( $val );
 }
```

Like this:

```
foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
        $key = stripslashes( $val );
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the error you see?

If it's about "Output started" check twice both `db.php` and `checkuser.php` if they have any characters out of php tags `<?php ?>` it will cause `header` to not work. In most cases space is forgotten around somewhere.